# flutter timer periodic with starting 00 min

Tags: flutter, dart, timer

After setting, I want this checking to be started HH:00, not just after 1 min from set.
Do you have any idea of it?

```dart
 Timer runAlarm() {
    return Timer.periodic(Duration(minutes: 1), (timer) async {
      workTodo();
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept to get data on start point will be calling the work method before assigning the timer.

```dart
  workToDo() {
    print("data");
  }

  Timer runAlarm() {
    workToDo();
    return Timer.periodic(duration, (timer) {
      workToDo();
    });
  }
```

Comment: When I set 10:47:18, the checking will work at 10:48:18. But I want it to check 10:48:00 and 10:49:00 and so on.

Comment: I'm coming from javascript and it makes perfect sense. It's like calling method workToDo once and then call it on setInterval.